# Order categories by number of downloads of the items in them

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables:

**Items**

```
| id | name   | downloads | category_id |
|----|--------|-----------|-------------|
| 1  | Item 1 | 5         | 1           |
| 2  | Item 2 | 7         | 1           |
| 3  | Item 3 | 23        | 2           |
```

**Categories**

```
| id | name       |
|----|------------|
| 1  | Somecategory |
| 2  | Someothercategory |
| 3  | Somecategory2 |
```

I am currently using a basic query:

```
$cats = Category::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('parent', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
```

But I would like the categories to be sorted by the number of their items' downloads.

So if someone searches for "some" to return `Someothercategory` first, because its item (Item 3) has the most downloads.

Thanks!

Comment: If some categories have multiple items, do you want to order by sum of their downloads or max values?

Comment: I want the sum of their downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of joining the tables, grouping by the category name and using sum on the downloads.

Using SQL, that could be solved using:

```
SELECT c.name, SUM(downloads) AS downloads
FROM items i
INNER JOIN categories c ON i.category_id=c.id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%other%'
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY downloads DESC
```

The next step would be to search how to achieve this using Eloquent, if that's what you desire.

If you want to simplify things, you could also create a View on the database containing this code. With that you would only need to:

```
SELECT name, downloads 
FROM viewCategoryDownloads 
WHERE c.name LIKE '%other%'
ORDER BY downloads DESC
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [COUNT()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/counting-rows.html&ved=0ahUKEwiJsID14PPMAhUHjywKHYIGBccQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNEWYmZU1eMqiypBPZkp5lVOms29KQ&sig2=QLXq1Pt6fwYY7NJy-DqYSg) function and [column aliases](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php&ved=0ahUKEwiCoeyj4fPMAhWHiywKHbgrCbUQFggoMAQ&usg=AFQjCNGgNLM3LfqVO0dgKat1DZ_EjmYhww&sig2=6kqb4BY9s6vzWj27WHyFsQ). In a laravel context you can use [raw queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#aggregates)